# How break ties after getting rank

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that gets me a users rank in a table of scores.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *, @rank:=@rank + 1 rank
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        user_id, SUM(round_total) TotalPoints
    FROM
        sx14sp_mem_picks
    GROUP BY user_id) s, (SELECT @rank:=0) init
    ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC) r
WHERE
    user_id = 22234
```

There is a problem with ties. I have a table field "pick_date" that i would like to use to break ties with. The user who made his picks first beats the tie.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sx14sp_mem_picks.pickdate is the field to break ties then in the order by sx14sp_mem_picks subquery, add 
min( pickdate) asc

This will put the earliest pickdate first - you have to use MIN() bc you need to use an aggregate function given the use of "group by".

Answer (score 0):

You need to `order` by the pick date in addition to the total points.  However, you are talking about multiple rows per user.  So, let's take the *last* pick date:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, (@rank:=@rank + 1) as rank
      FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(round_total) as TotalPoints, max(pick_date) as max_pick_date
            FROM sx14sp_mem_picks
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) s CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rank := 0) init
     ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC, max_pick_date asc
    ) r
WHERE user_id = 22234;
```

Comment: this won't work bc you put the reference to "pickdate" outside the subquery where it needs to be - it will have no context

also, MIN() needs to be used bc he wanted lower integer rank given to user with the earliest pickdate

Comment: @spioter . . . Fixed the problem with the pic date.  I think the OP wants the lower rank to the *last* pick date.  According to the question, there are multiple rows per user, and hence multiple pick dates.

Comment: OP said: "The user who made his picks first beats the tie." In my book, "first" = min()

also users are ranked based on @rank which is 0 for the highest score and increments by 1 for each user with a lower score - so I believe "beats the tie" means a higher score and *lower* `code`@rank

your adjustment is an improvement but users will still have tied @rank - the OP will have to decide to use your method if he wants tied `code`@rank or my suggestion if he wants each user to get a different score (assuming no ties on both TotalPoints and pickdate)

Comment: @spioter . . . You're not getting it.  The `order by` is sorting in ascending order.  That is where the "first" comes in.  The issue is that there is a different date on each pick (as the OP describes the data).  Which date of the many possibilities do you assign to the user?  I'm choosing the *last* which would be when the "pick" is complete, based on the phrase "user who made his picks first beats the tie".  Notice the plural on "picks".

Comment: good point - it all depends on what OP is trying to score on - users that made their first pick sooner or their last pick sooner.